# Shell script to download a file from URL with user authentication

Tags: unix

I have to download an .csv file from the URL with usrname and password which I have  by using shell script to my unix staging location. How can i do this?

Comment: I don't think that's physically possible. If it were, the Internet would be full of tips on how to do it.

Comment: `wget` and `curl` are designed to do this, but have a dozen or more options that you'll have to parse. Find a tutorial for whichever you have available on your system, try to get it working from the command line, and then edit your question with exact cmds you have executed and the exact error msgs you get. Good luck.